# I want to prevent a window from opening when an application launches

Tags: windows, batch-file, startup

I have a program the opens a window, reads a config file, then closes the window a fraction of a second later, then continues running in background.  I want to be able to start this program one way or another without the window appearing in the first place.

Is there a way for me to launch the program (preferably on PC startup) but suppress any windows it creates?

I do not have the source code for the program in question.  In that regard I am an end-user.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code that "opens a window, reads a config file, then closes the window".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a vbs script to open it:

```
set obj = createobject("wscript.shell")
obj.run "prog.exe",0,false
```

call that prog.vbs or whatever, and put it in:

```
"%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\startup"
```